# Convert NSData to Base-64 wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64, nsdata

I convert **NSString to byte Array**. It ok, then I convert **NSData to base64 is wrong**. if "**010203040506**" is right but with high number (exam: @"333435363738") is wrong. This is my code. Please help me.

**In Android: ISIjJCUm and iOS: MzQ1Njc4.**

```
NSString *command = @"333435363738";
NSMutableData *commandToSend= [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
unsigned long whole_byte;
char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
int i;
for (i=0; i < [command length] /2; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%d",[command characterAtIndex:i*2]);
    NSLog(@"%d",[command characterAtIndex:i*2 + 1]);
    byte_chars[0] = [command characterAtIndex:i*2];
    byte_chars[1] = [command characterAtIndex:i*2 + 1];
    whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
    [commandToSend appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];
}



NSString *base64String;
if ([commandToSend respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)]) {
    base64String = [commandToSend base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+
} else {
    base64String = [commandToSend base64Encoding];                              // pre iOS7
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produces the string `MzQ1Njc4` which is the bas64 encoding of the bytes `0x33`, `0x34`, `0x35`, `0x36`, `0x37`, `0x38`. This appears to be what the code is meant to do.

The string `ISIjJCUm` is the base64 encoding of `0x21`, `0x22`, `0x23`, `0x24`, `0x25`, `0x26`.

Note that `0x21` is `33` decimal. So it looks like you were either meant to interpret the string as decimal on iOS or as hex on Android.